# WhatsApp sharing link for emails

Tags: html, email, whatsapp

I have a WhatsApp sharing link:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=How to become our friend%20https://smartmother.me/pages/top-5-baby-s-first-week-tips/" target="_blank" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">WhatsApp a friend now&nbsp;»</a>
```

I'm sending a link by using the HTML emails. When I open the email, the link is not working. I'm using Klaviyo for my emails.

Here is my link in the received email (opened with Crome DevTools) http://prntscr.com/dbgbj6 As you can see, it's broken.

I spent a lot of time for finding a solution to the problem but the answer was never found. Who knows a solution to this problem? Tell me please!

Comment: Depends on the email client. Better to use a normal link, that redirects to this kind of URL.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your solution. Can you explain it with more details please.

Comment: Let's say, give the email link to be: `http://nazar.com/send-whatsapp-message` and in that link, redirect to `whatsapp://send?text=How to become our friend%20https://smartmother.me/pages/top-5-baby-s-first-week-tips/` - Does this make sense?

Comment: Sounds good. I will try your solution. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing the link breaks because of the un-encoded spaces. Try converting the spaces to HTML-entities, ie. `%20`. If you're using some sort of server-side language, for instance PHP, you can run the URL through `htmlentities()` before sending it.

Comment: Please tell me the best option how to make redirect of link as recommended mr. Praveen Kumar

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine from the mobile browser when there are no spaces in the link (if there are convert them into dashes "-", but not into `+` not `%20` and neither `&#43;` because somewhy whatsapp translates that to spaces and it breaks the link).

Try simply removing the `%20` before the url.